# Angularjs: ng-click has no method '$apply'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I append DOM element to body. Wrote the code in factory.

```
var templateElement = angular.element('<div class="popup modal-body"><div class="button-cancel" type="button" ng-click="closePopup()"></div>'+content+'</div>');
    var scope = {};
    scope.closePopup = function(){
      var popup = angular.element(document.querySelector('.popup'));
      popup.remove();
    }

    var clonedElement = $compile(templateElement)(scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {
      body.append(clonedElement);
    });
```

everything works except the ng-click. I got this error when I click the div:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$apply'
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: where did you write this code? in directive?

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin I wrote it in a factory.

Comment: @zeroflagL I did post that

Comment: @catwoman My apologies, I missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#usage_returns)**, the function returned by `$compile()` takes a **[Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)** object as its first argument. You supply a normal JS object (which does not have an `$apply` method of course).

If you want to create a new scope, you can inject the `$rootScope` (through **[Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)**) and use its `$new()` method:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($rootScope) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ...
});
```

---

<sub>It seems a little bizarre to create an new scope inside a factory though, so providing more details on what you are ultimately trying to achieve might help someone suggest a better approach.</sub>